# How does Tezos voting process work in practice?

Tags: voting, amendment, governance

The upcoming voting process to amend the Tezos protocol is an exciting opportunity to see on-chain governance in action!

For the benefit of all and reference, it would be great to lay down here instructions or pointer to reference article on how to perform voting when not delegating tokens to a baker.

Answer (score 7):

As a self baker, you can vote [via Ledger](https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/voting-on-tezos-with-your-ledger-nano-s-8d75f8c1f076).

Answer (score 5):

[image]

There is already a Guide from Obsidian, about Voting with a Ledger Nano

SOURCE: https://github.com/tezoscommunity/FAQ/blob/master/Compile_Mainnet.md